# Baggage issues on Qatar Airways ticket

Tags: luggage

I am being issued a Qatar Airways ticket for Vancouver to Karachi via LA and Doha. However I was surprised to see that checked baggage allowance was 1 piece. Even though the Qatar Airways website says any flights originating US/Canada 2 piece allowance for checked baggage. I am very confused and the customer service for Qatar Airways has not been very helpful in giving me a written response and wants me to get a verbal answer from their reservation desk in Canada. 
(Note when I try to purchase the ticket on Qatar Airways website it does show two pieces allowed, however I used a travel agent to purchase my ticket and now the ticket reciept says 1 piece)

Comment: In my experience, travel agents are not very good at figuring out baggage allowances for multi-carrier itineraries. Does your Vancouver-LA flight have a Qatar flight number? What does it say when you look at your reservation on Qatar's website?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to login to qatarairways.com with your booking reference and your last name, it will give you the correct details of your flight - along with your baggage allowances.